# Github pages : build failed => how to debug?

Tags: internationalization, jekyll, github-pages

I have a message from github telling me that my page build failed.

Without any more information. :(

Of course I have read [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/)...

But how can I have more info on what's going wrong?

It builds really fine locally:

```
jekyll build
Configuration file: /srv/jekyll/_config.yml
            Source: /srv/jekyll
       Destination: /srv/jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
Building site for default language: "fr" to: /srv/jekyll/_site
Loading translation from file /srv/jekyll/_i18n/fr.yml
   GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.
Building site for language: "en" to: /srv/jekyll/_site/en
Loading translation from file /srv/jekyll/_i18n/en.yml
Build complete
                    done in 1.265 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

Here's my `_config.yml`:

```
title: My site
description: My description
email: email@example.com
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: example
github_username:  example

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
  - jekyll-redirect-from

languages: ['fr', 'en']
exclude_from_localizations: ['assets', 'CNAME']
defaultLang: fr
languageNames:
  fr: Français
  en: English
  it: Italiano
```

Any tip?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin `jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin` is not supported by GitHub Pages.
Test if your site builds fine locally with `github-pages` gem instead of `jekyll` gem

Comment: Indeed. :( I moved to netlify as a hosting solution then: https://www.netlify.com